# Convert ArrayList<<NameValuePair>> to string android java

Tags: java, android

How to Convert ArrayList<> to string ...

Details:

step1: send e-mail address to php mySql database 
step2: if email address match database content, echoed success
step3: retrieved the php echoed value ("success")
step4: assign the the response to a string phpEchoedVal
step5: compare phpEchoedVal with "success"
step6: write email to sd card

is this one ok 
//url = email address

ArrayList nameValuePair = new ArrayList(1);

```
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", url));

  try {
        //open an httpclient connection

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strLink);

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));


            //response retrieve "success" echoed from server

        ResponseHandler<String> handleResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();

            //converts server response to string.

        String phpEchoVal = httpclient.execute(httppost, handleResponse);


        txtInfo.setText(phpEchoVal);

        String containEmail = txtInfo.getText().toString();



            //compare response from server with local string

            // if successful write email to sd card

        if ((containEmail.equals("success"))){

            //create a new text file

            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/moLarouteReg.txt");

            myFile.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

            myOutWriter.append(containEmail);

            //close writer
            myOutWriter.close();

        fOut.close();

        //Open menu

          Intent openMenu = new Intent("com.molaroute.mu.Menu");

            startActivity(openMenu);

            finish();

        Log.d("test","fileWritten: "+myOutWriter);

        }else {



            ...
        }
   }
```

Comment: Your title almost literally tells you how to achieve this.

Comment: yes but in practice it don't work

Comment: Then tell us what you expect to happen.. And what does ArrayList<> have to do with what you are trying to achieve in your code snippet.

Comment: i want to compare whether a namevaluepair in ArrayList match a String

Comment: In that case, your title is wrong, your question in your post is wrong and your code snippet is wrong. Please try to elaborate correctly in your question(edit it) what you want. And don't let us guess what you want.

Comment: ok. but i just want to know how to convert the phpEchoVal into a simple string. The question has been set for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question; how to match strings in an array list(containting name value pair objects) to other strings:

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> lst = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //Instantiate arraylist
    lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fruit", "apple")); //add entry
    lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("animal", "monkey")); //add entry
    String strToCompareAgainst = "apple"; //str to compare to for example
    for(NameValuePair valPair : lst) { //foreach loop
        if(valPair.getValue().equals(strToCompareAgainst)) { //retrieve value of the current NameValuePair and compare
            Log.d("login","moooooo"); //success
        }
    }
```

You can also check if a text contains another text instead of checking for equality.

```
String str1 = "I am a success";
String str2 = "success";

if(str1.contains(str2)) {}  //Evaluates to true, because str1 contains the word "success"

if(str1.equals(str2)) {} //Evaluates to false, because str1 does not hold the same value as str2
```

Ofcourse you can do alot more, but this should give you the basic idea..

For your second question:

HttpClient.execute() returns an HttpResponse.
From HttpResponse you can call getEntity which returns an HttpEntity
From HttpEntity you can call getContent which returns an InputStream.

This InputStream you can convert to string. Example conversion code snippets are widely on the net.

so the code:

```
httpResponse = client.execute(post, _httpContext);
        //Set the response code from the request's responst.
        setResponseCode(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        //Retrieve the body of the response.
        entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if(entity != null) {
            //Retrieve the content from the body.
            _inStream = entity.getContent();
            //Convert the InputStream to String and set the String response to the returned value.
            setStringResponse(IOUtility.convertStreamToString(_inStream));
            //Close the InputStream.
            Log.d(TAG, getStringResponse());
        }
```

Note that IOUtility is self written class in this case.
I think there are other ways to convert a HttpResponse to a string, but this is how I do it.

_inStream is an InputStream, entity is an HttpEntity, the rest should be self explanatory.

Comment: if phpEchoVal is already in the form  ArrayList<NameValuePair> and i want to compare String "success" to the element in phpEchoVal. How to proceed

Comment: Do you mean phpEchoVal is of data type ArrayList<NameValuePair> or phpEchoVal is a NameValuePair inside an array list?  If phpEchoVal is an ArrayList<NameValuePair> you use: for(NameValuePair item : phpEchoVal) {}

Comment: i assigned httpclient.execute(httppost, handleResponse) to a string called phpEchoVal. httpclient.execute return an echoed php value. Sorry its a bit complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you want to achieve. You use a responseHandler, which will return a String if you defined handleResponse like ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); This is what you want, and what you have.. so what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i updated the question. i know its far from perfect but my goal is set in the question. hope you understand

Comment: I don't know which part is'nt working. I can give a tip; Remove the containsMail variable, because when you create it, you give it the exact same value as phpEchoVal, , you create even more overhead by retrieving the value from the textview and then copy it into the containsMail variable. You can do containsMail = phpEchoVal, which executes faster. Also, you don't need containsMail as a whole. Cause it contains the same value as phpEchoVal, whatever you do with containsMail you can do with phpEchoVal.

Comment: Ok, what matter is the condition if ((containEmail.equals("success"))) ... i want it to be true, ,meaning it matches. i want certify it is successful

Comment: if(containEmail.equals("success")) {} (note I removed 2 parenthesis) will ONLY return true if the value of containEmail is exactly "success", if containEmail holds for example sucesssss it will fail. If the value of containEmail can be more then only the string "success" then you should either try regular expressions, or the contains() method. So containsEmail.contains("success"); I can't really help you more then this. I have editted my answer (the for loop with the array list to reflect contains)

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<MyType> l = new ArrayList<MyType>();
// fill

System.out.println(l.toString());
```

Comment: @GrimJov then tell us what you expect it to do, i.e. what do you want to achieve? `toString()` definitely works, but it probably does not do want you want.

Comment: i want to compare whether a namevaluepair in ArrayList match a String

Comment: then u should iterate the list and append each element to a buffer and then get the string from that